# Rails 4 Getting a nested relation through a list of objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Need some help. I'm trying to fetch all related objects when working with a list of objects. E g

```
class Customer
  has_many :items
end

class Item
  has_many :costs
  belongs_to :customer
end

class Cost
  belongs_to :item
end
```

I want to be able to do something like this:

```
Customer.where(name: 'Test').items.costs
```

The problem seems to be that you cannot access the has_many relationship 'items' on a collection of customers.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Solution:
I went with the solution suggested by Nathan in the comment below:

```
Cost.where(item_id: Item.where(type: "hardware").pluck(:id))
```

It seemed like the cleanest way of using ActiveRecord to get the collection although it requires two SQL-queries.

Edit:
As dimakura mentions in a comment to his suggestion this might not be feasible since a large Array will have to be built in order to run the SQL.

Edit:
I just wanted to give you an update of what my final solution was. The reason I wanted to do this was to fetch data to be used for statistics in my application. For example "How much has a customer bought items for each month this year?".

Ultimately I decided that it just isn't feasible to use ActiveRecord to create statistics in every case which led me to use pure SQL instead. It is possible that there is some überclever way of solving THIS case the way I wanted, but this case is a very simple one. There are others that are harder to solve.

Comment: Your associations are fine.. the problem is your query. What you're trying to get is list of costs related only to items that a customer purchased -- am I correct? So you do this: `Cost.joins(item: [:customer]).where(items: { customers: { name: "Test" })`

Comment: You are correct. However, I would like to be able to fetch all costs pertaining to any given collection of items. For example I have a scope defined on Item that fetches all items of a certain type. I would like to be able to get all costs on that type like this

Item.type(:hardware).costs

Comment: You can't get a collection from a collection unless you use a sub-query. Something like `Cost.where(item_id: Item.were(type: "hardware").pluck(:id))`

Comment: @AndyB it's not an optimal solution. See my updated answer below.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, define the following relations in you models:

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items
  has_many :costs, through: :items
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer
  has_many :costs
end

class Cost < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :item
end
```

Now you can easily select this relations.

If you need to select `costs` from given `customer`, it's just:

```
customer.costs
```

In more complicated cases, you might need to select all costs for a group of customers. In this case you write queries with `joins`.

Let's select costs for customers from US:

```
Cost.joins(item: :customer).where('customers.country=?','US')
```

You can query now not only by customer properties, but by item properties as well.

Hope it solves your problem.

Comment: This might be the best way. It is just inconvenient that flat_map (and map) returns an Array and not an Activerecord Collection to be able to continue chaining the query.

Comment: This is nice, but I'd rather not add a transient relationship when it is not necessary, and I don't think it solves my problem. It is rather that I want to use some collection of entities and get a collection of an associated has_many relationship.

Comment: Unfortunately you do need transient relationships. Solution you use has several limitations. Here are some: 1. `IN` operator is limited in size of array in many RDMS systems; 2. You need to create whole item ids array, which might be too large. So I still advocate to use solution describe above.

Comment: Hmm, interesting points raised.. But it's still a different solution from the one I hoped for. It seems to me that the flat_map solution you suggested before is closer and might be what I'm going to go with in the end. I will have to think about it though.

Comment: @AndyB as I understand your problem was to get all `costs` associated with given `customer`? Right?

Comment: Yes, in this specific example. But the question I'm raising is the more general which is contained in the headline. How to get all Cost from ANY collection of Item.

Comment: @AndyB I finally solved your problem :) Thanks, it was interesting to work on.

Comment: Yes, kind of. But I still went with the pure SQL approach since there are much more complex cases. Thanks for the effort! =)

Comment: Can you please accept this answer if it answered the question you stated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe i'm wrong but according to me you need to do something like

```
class Customer
  has_many :items
end

class Item
  belongs_to :customers
  has_many :costs
end

class Cost
  belongs_to :items
  attr_accessor :value
end
```

Comment: I have actually done that now that i look a bit closer. Will update my question. Thanks.